# Turnaround animation

Tags: unity, animation, spritesheet, animator

So I have a Moose with 3 animations: **idle**, **walk**, **turnaround**.

**Idle** and **walk** are mostly self explanatory while the spritesheet for the **turnaround** animation looks like this:

[image]

I set an **animator** with **3 animations** and **transitions** going as follows:

- From **Idle** to **Walking** and **back**. (trigger is an int parameter speed (0 = idle, >0 = walking)
- From **Idle** to **Turnaround** and **back**. (trigger is a bool parameter (true = turnaround, false = idle)

Basically I want to have the moose stay **idle**, then **walk** from point A to point B, then stay **idle**, then **turnaround**, then stay **idle**, then **walk** from B to A, then stay **idle**, then **turnaround**, then **repeat the whole cycle**.

To be easier to understand, I'm attaching a video showcasing everything from above including the animator with the states and parameters:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0MuMurlICQ

The problem is, when the turnaround animation finishes, the moose flips on X and back for a half a second before going into idle and continuing to walk.

My code for that part looks like this:

```
this.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("MooseTurnaround", true); //go into turnaround animation
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.6f); //duration of the turnaround animation
this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
this.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("MooseTurnaround", false); //go into idle animation
yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
```

I can't exactly wrap my head on why this is happening and how can it be fixed. The turnaround animation has **loop disabled**. When it hits the last frame what exactly happens?